# C: reading a file without printing the same line twice

Tags: c, file, io, getopt

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, but I'm new to C and I want to know if my logic is the most efficient way to solve this problem.

The easiest way I can think of is:

1. read the first line
2. store the line in a buffer1
3. read the second line
4. store the second line in a buffer2
5. if buffer1 != buffer2, print buffer1 and erase buffer1. store line 3 in buffer 1. repeat from step 4.
6. if buffer1 = buffer2, erase buffer1, store line 3 in buffer 1, and repeat from step 4.

If the file contains:

```
ok ok

ok

ok
```

the result should be:

```
ok ok

ok
```

Comment: Excellent! Now: try it in actual code.(and,once it works, try to do it with only one buffer ...)

Comment: Is there a function that reads a file line by line in C? I tried fgets and getLine but those didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Only one buffer:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char buff[100];
int diff,ch;
unsigned pos;

for(pos=0,diff=1;;){
        ch = getc(stdin);

        if (ch != buff[pos] ) {
            if (!diff) for ( ; diff < pos; diff++) putc(buff[diff], stdout);
            diff=1;
            }
        if (ch == EOF)break;
        if (diff) putc(ch,stdout);
        buff[pos++] = ch;
        if (pos >= sizeof buff) {;} //handle overflow here
        if (ch == '\n') {diff = pos = 0; }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> store line 3 in buffer 1

is not what you want to have. Dont store it at all. Its hard to understand what you are trying to do here by the way. If you dont want to print the 3th line of this example, simply ignore the step 5 part where you print it